# Problema al mostrar valores en un alert con variable en PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery

Lo que deseo es mostrar el contenido de mi variable `$serie`

```
alert(<?php echo $serie; ?>);
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando el valor de `$serie = '003'` si funciona mi alerta pero si el valor es `'FF01'` ya no lo resuelve, al parecer solo toma el valor de la variable cuando es número.

Answer (score 3):

Agrega comillas simples o dobles `alert("<?=$serie?>");`

Comment: Gracias Ruben esa es la solucion <?php echo "'" . $abrvComprobante . "'"; ?>

Comment: @RubenHernandez como puedo contactarme con usted

Comment: Genial @JoseMariano asi lo resuelves desde PHP, la solución que te propongo lo soluciona desde JS. Pura vida!!! :)

Comment: @x-rw cuentame en que puedo apoyarte? Soy novato en la comunidad y no se aun si existe algún buzón privado

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Ruben también soy nuevo, todavia no he verificado si hay un buzon voy a buscar y te informo si encuentras algo me avisas no se si permita dejar correos personales

Comment: @JoseMariano a ti mucho éxito, busquemos ese buzon :)